# React-router-dom: Render two components under one route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                path="/test/:id"
                component={Question1} />
              <Route
                path="/test/:id"
                component={Question2} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

I need to navigate from Question1, which has id of 1, to question2 which should have id of 2. I can navigate to question1 from test without problem, but when I want to go to question to using `this.props.history.push('/test/2')` the URL changes but I dont get navigated to question2.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a single `Question` component which handles the `id` and  displays the appropriate question.

You can do the same using the `render` method of `Route`

```
  <Route
     path="/test/:id"
     render={(props)=>{
             switch(props.match.params.id){
                  case "1": return <Question1/>;
                  case "2" : return <Question2/>;
                  default : return null;
              }
     }}
  />
```

**EDIT**: Corrected code after comment

Comment: Works great just missing params in props.match.params.id

Answer (score 2):

This issue is that `<Switch>` will match the first component under the `<BrowserRouter/>` in this case. If it doesn't match the first path, it will try the second. That is how `Switch` works. So in your example the path template of `path=/test/:id` actually matches both `/test/1` and `/test/2`, and that `Route` always renders `Question1` and never `Question2`. Check out the docs here
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch.

One quick thing you can do is if you know you only have two `Question`s then you can do

```
          <Route exact
            path="/test/1"
            component={Question1}
          />
          <Route exact
            path="/test/2"
            component={Question2}
          />
```

Which will solve your problem immediately, but I don't recommend this as it gets unreasonable as you get more `Question`s. A better set-up is what @palsrealm recommends.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one route, and load the right question in your component :

```
<Route path="/test/:id" component={Question} />

// Question.js
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Question {this.props.params.id}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

doc : [route-with-parameters](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params#adding-a-route-with-parameters)